# Is it possible to get refresh token using OidcUserRequest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2client

I am loading oidcUser from **OidcUserRequest** in my **Oauth2UserService** implementation class.

```java
@Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OidcUser user = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
        List<GrantedAuthority> rolesAsAuthorities = getRolesAsAuthorities(user);
        
        CustomOidcUserDetailsImpl customUser = new CustomOidcUserDetailsImpl(user, rolesAsAuthorities);
        customUser.setFullName(getFullName(user));
        customUser.setTelephone(getTelephone(user));
        customUser.setEmail(getEmail(user));
        return customUser;
    }
```

The problem is that i just can get **OauthAccessToken** and **IdToken** from **OidcUserRequest**. Are there any ways of getting **Oauth2RefreshToken** in my service? 
I get **id,access,refresh tokens** if i exchange **authorization code** for tokens manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

    Authentication authentication =SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService
                .loadAuthorizedClient(
                        "wso2", // client registrationId
                        authentication.getName());
    Oauth2RefreshToken refreshToken = client.getRefreshtoken();
```